# Android Market Application Updates

Tags: android, google-play

Quick question about android market application updates. If I have an app on the market and release an update, is there a way to ensure that the users download the new update?

I.e. Does the app tells the user there is an update, or does it stop working until they download an update?

Or should I be writing code in my apps to stop working after a fixed period thus forcing the user to download the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the Market Application will let the user that updates are available for one or more of their installed applications via a Status Bar notification, but users aren't forced to install the update.

I think stopping the application working after a time period, forcing to the user to install a new update is not a good thing to do because:

- A user might not want to update your application if it's working.  Updating a lot of applications via the Market can be chore due to the interminable prompts so I sometimes don't get round to updating applications as soon as updates are available.
- It forces you to release possibly needless updates when the previous version is about to time out.
- It's not very nice to the users.

Why do you want to force updates on users?  If you explain the problem you are trying to solve by doing this someone might be able to give you a better solution.

The only thing you can do to make it more likely that users will upgrading update the description of your application in the Market to include the benefits of upgrading, as users can read the update description before deciding whether to upgrade.

Comment: I want to ensure users get the latest version of my software. I released a beta app and want to make sure that the current user base get my new version with bug fixes and new functionality (would also hopefully get them to up the rating on my app as a result)

Comment: If an application is clearly marked as "Beta" or "Pre-release" then I guess there is an argument for it time-expiring, but I still wouldn't recommend this for an app publicly released on the Market.   The best thing to do is update the description of the app to cover the benefits of upgrading as users can read this before deciding whether to upgrade.

Comment: But they still have to go to the market, search and then find the update. Some sort of notification would be good so that they are more likely to find the new version

Comment: @Gaz - as I said in my post, the Market application does notify users when updates are available.

Comment: ok, no probs, just never get any notifications on my Hero

Comment: A Google found this screenshot: http://the-gadgeteer.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Notification2-281x500.png  The Market notification is the bottom one.

Comment: You only get notifications from the market if you open the market app every now and again. It really should be a un-stoppable service...

Answer (score 1):

I have heard about notifications sometimes working and sometimes not.  My users tell me they are NOT notified when I update my application but that when they view their "My Downloads" from the Market application on their phone, it shows "Update Available" next to the application.  If they do not go into "My Downloads" they never know an update is available.

```
"Or should I be writing code in my apps to stop working after a fixed
 period thus forcing the user to download the new version?"
```

I would not recommend this unless the application will no longer work w/o the update.  The Android Market is so fickle that sometimes applications dissapear from "My Downloads" when a carrier updates their system software on your user's phone.  If that happens and your application expires your users will not be able to access the application until Google fixes the problem which can take a week or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for new versions on your server and then programmatically direct them to the market place:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.yourapp...")));
```

Comment: how to check android latest version on APP store??