# Update default app automaticall from market

Tags: android

I have a lower version App installed in device using adb install command. I have a higher version of App in Android Market. I would make update the app in device automatically from Android Market. I saw the similar post below:
[Prompt Android App User to Update App if current version <> market version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555098/prompt-android-app-user-to-update-app-if-current-version-market-version)
[Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)
but Neither of those posts answer this question.
They mush have some solution. just like Goole Maps and Gmail does. I don't know how Google Maps does it? 
someone suggest uses
    http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
But it failed for me on code below: (android 3.2) 
        session.login("mymail@gmail.com",password);
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this is not really possible since your app wasn't first installed from the Android Market, so the market doesn't know about this "purchase", doesn't track updates so it won't prompt the user to update, or auto-update the app. 
The only way to do it is to install the app from the market, keeping the "auto-update" checkbox on.

Comment: I think it must have a way to do it. For example, Google Map and Gmail App can make automatically update.

Comment: Google Maps and Gmail Apps are signed with the same signature as the Android Market, giving them extra privileges that your app can't get.

Comment: So Pluse news, Adobe Flash player 11 are signed with the same signaure as Android Market?

Comment: the Android Market updates those apps for you, they don't update themselves. If Pulse News and Flash Player were bundled in your phone at purchase, then there's a very high chance that they are treated just as Google Maps or Gmail.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I sign the Android Market signature into my app (I think device manufacture can sign it for me) and put it into device manufacture source code, the new image file can make my app automatically updated from the app signed in the same signature in Android Market. Could you please help me to confirm it?