# Not Showing Update in Playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I pushed an update for an application to playstore.

My sdk level for both versions

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

In android kitkat 4.4.4, I have old version(V1.1.1) installed already.

[image]

[image]

In playstore it is showing that it is Updated to latest version(V1.1.2)

[image]

But Still it is not showing "Update" option in already installed mobile. When I install in a new mobile(Android Jellybean 4.1.2) it is installing later version(V1.1.2).

[image]

Can anyone know what might be the reason?

Comment: How long time ago did you upload? usually it takes several hours and up to 1 day after updating apk...

Comment: as it is showing in the above image. I uploaded on 21 April

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849889/how-to-notifiy-users-about-an-android-app-update sometimes devices do not receive notifications about updates, so you have to update it manually.

Comment: It is not showing to do for manual Update in the app page. As shown in above image

Comment: have you added any new permissions in manifest in new version.

Comment: No new permissions added. Did some small bug fixes

Comment: Same issue here....did you find the solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

If your update is not visible to the users, the major reason is there is something in your app which have reduced the supported devices.

You can go to playstore console -> App bundle explorer -> check the details and check for supported devices

[image]

This might help you.