# How to alert the users that there is a new Updation available in google play store

Tags: android

I have an application on the play store and for first time i have updated it. How to alert the users that there is a new Updation available in google play store through the app when they open it,just like a notification or alert and redirect to that linked apk page.

startActivity(new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novtory.provider") ));

I think the above code may help to link the page but i want to know how to send a notification when there is a new update available without using any third party library.Please help me out.

Comment: You really shouldn't worry about it. The users will get their update (usually automatically) through Google Play. You don't need to let your users know. Especially since it isn't guaranteed that all users will be able to get the update at the exactly same time.

Comment: https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager Take a look at this

Comment: thats a third pary library right @  Arjun Hegde

Comment: Its under Apache License!!

Comment: Did u check this lib https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager?

Answer (score 0):

> You do not need to do anything specific for this. Since you mentioned
>   that you are using Android Play, the update notification is taken care
>   of by Google Play.
>
> You need to just update the **APK** with higher `versionCode` and
>   Google Play should do the rest.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878292/4427731

Comment: will it automatically send a notification, msg or anything to user that an update is available

Answer (score 0):

In your first screen or splash screen call a web api which will return you the latest version code. And then compare it with the current app's version code. If it is not latest show user an alert dialog that he needs to update the app. And then redirect the user to play store with your app using Intent. Note that you have to update the latest version code on your server every time you upload the update.

Comment: thank but how to do that just insert the version code in the database and check every time or is there any other method

Comment: you have to call that web service just like any other http request