# React Native Notification About New App Release (App Store and Play Store)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-play, app-store

We are about to release our new React Native app to Apple App Store and Google Play Store.

We know we'll be updating our app version every few weeks. We'd like to add an ability to update our users that their current version is deprecated, and help them navigate to the app/play stores to download the new release.

What is the best practice for this task?

Notice we're using Firebase for push notification so we're able to leverage both Firebase [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/) and [In-App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging/)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849889/how-to-notifiy-users-about-an-android-app-update

Comment: Short: Google Play Store updates installed apps referring to the settings each user has. E.g.: Some users turned off automatic updates. So you can decide to send notifications via firebase additionally.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). Use that to configure the minimum required app version, and have your app check it on start-up. If the current version is less than the required version, ask the user to update on Play using a [Play URL link/intent](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app).

Please please please don't do what some developers do and scrape the play store for the current version.

Comment: "Please please please don't do what some developers do and scrape the play store for the current version." - Just curious, why not?