# Notify users when there is new updates in Android

Tags: android, dialog, push-notification

Is there anyway to notify the users (inside of my application) if newer versions is published? perhaps through Dialog?

Comment: Yes, you can use Dialog, but you may be more specific if you want more help.

Comment: Lets say, you installed my app today, and the next day I published a newer version. What I really want to do is, once you launch my application I want some dialog to pop out inside of my application notifying the users that newer version is published in the Market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in web client android application we make a request to the server for getting the current version. 
Use

```
String versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0 ).versionName;
```

And compare and notify the user with a dialog.

Comment: How would I implement this in my dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Santosh's solution just allow you to access to the "android:versionName" attribute in your manifest.
look at [Android Market Application Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175945/android-market-application-updates).
It could help you